# Is adding seconds wrong way to browse through the time in PHP?

Tags: php

I iterate through time by adding 86400 (the count of seconds in the 1 day) to list the dates.

```
 define("DAY_SEC", 86400);
 for ($i = strtotime("2016-10-01"); $i<=strtotime("2016-11-05"); $i = $i + DAY_SEC){
        echo Date("Y-m-d, H:i:s", $i). ' = '. $i . '<br/>';
 }
```

But look on the date "2016-10-30". It is there twice but with different hours

```
2016-10-28, 00:00:00 = 1477605600 
2016-10-29, 00:00:00 = 1477692000    
2016-10-30, 00:00:00 = 1477778400 <- here
2016-10-30, 23:00:00 = 1477864800 <- here
2016-10-31, 23:00:00 = 1477951200
```

What do I wrong?

thanx

Comment: you should be using DateTime with a DateInterval for addition, to be (nearly) completely safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add or subtract or do any other math with timestamps to calculate past or future dates. Your code will fail after `2016-11-05` in U.S. and some other time zones because that is the end of Daylight Saving Time this year.  `strtotime()` is aware of this, so use it with `"+1 day"` or something similar:

```
for ($i = strtotime("2016-10-01"); $i<=strtotime("2016-11-05"); $i = strtotime("+1 day", $i)){
        echo Date("Y-m-d, H:i:s", $i). ' = '. $i . '<br/>';
}
```

It turns out `2016-10-30` is the end of Daylight Saving Time in many other places, so the time zone you are using is subject to that change.

Comment: Excelent.... I would be in mistake perhaps whole year without noticing anything wrong... October - What a chance... Thanks a lot..

Answer (score -1):

It is called DST(Daylight Savings Time). Try using `strtotime()`.

```
$start = strtotime("2016-10-01");
$end = strtotime("2016-11-05");
$interval = 1; //in days
for ($i = $start; $i<=$end; $i = $i + strtotime("+".$interval." days", $i)){
    echo Date("Y-m-d, H:i:s", $i). ' = '. $i . '<br/>';
 }
```